# Can I install Tensorflow on both Python 2 and 3?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've installed Tensorflow using Python 3 (pip3 install). Now, since Jupyter Notebook is using Python 2, thus the python command is linked to python2.7, all the codes in Jupyter Notebook get error (ImportError: No module named tensorflow).

Question: Can I install Tensorflow running side by side for both Python 2 and 3?

Comment: I believe you absolutely can by using VirtualEnv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do. Easy step is install python anaconda then create environment with python 2.7 and python 3. Install Tensorflow for both environment

Comment: I'm using Raspberry Pi 3. Is it still the same?